# How to flush redis cache using SoapUI

Tags: soapui

Is there any way to automate the process of redis cache clearance using SoapUI. Is it possible via groovy Script?

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do it through Groovy. Probably your best approach is:

- Create your own Java library using something like Lettuce (see [Introduction to Lettuce – the Java Redis Client](https://www.baeldung.com/java-redis-lettuce)) or Jedis ([Intro to Jedis – the Java Redis Client Library](https://www.baeldung.com/jedis-java-redis-client-library)) and expose the functionality you need through a simple interface, for example `flushall(String password, String host, Integer port, String database);`
- Wrap your interface and the Lettuce or Jedis dependencies into a JAR file and drop this into soapUI's `bin/ext` directory. After you restart, the JAR will be available in soapUI's classpath.
- Call out to that interface from within a soapUI Groovy Test Step to do the Redis things you need.

Comment: Thanks @craigcaulfield. I found the solution

Answer (score 0):

1. Place the jedis jar file under SOAPUI_HOME/bin/ext folder of soapUI, then restart soapui
2. Write the below groovy script Code:
   import redis.clients.jedis.Jedis

   Jedis jedis = new Jedis("Host")
   jedis.connect()
   jedis.flushDB()
3. Run the script